# Asymptotic behaviour of $f$ and $f'+f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, asymptotics

> Let $f~:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ map. How do you prove that if $f'+f$ vanish when $t\to +\infty$ so do $f$?

If $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty} f(t)=l$ with $l\neq 0$ :

I first look at the case $l$ **finite :** we have $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty} f'(t)=-l$ so for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $C>0$ such for all $t>C$, $|f(t)-l|$ and $|f'(t)+l|$ are both $\leq \varepsilon$. But I can't find a contradiction.

We know that $f'$ has a limit in $+\infty$ does not implies that there exist an asymptote so I don't really know what to do.

I also tried to write $g=f+f'$ and write $f$ has a solution of a differantial equation on $g$.

Any help will be appriaciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $h \colon t \mapsto f(t)e^t$. The assumption on $f$ says that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $x$ such that $\lvert h'(t)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon e^{t}$ for $t \geqslant x$. Then, for $y > x$ we have

$$\lvert h(y)\rvert = \Biggl\lvert h(x) + \int_x^y h'(t)\,dt\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \lvert h(x)\rvert + \varepsilon \int_x^y e^t\,dt < \lvert h(x)\rvert + \varepsilon e^y,$$

and hence

$$\lvert f(y)\rvert = \lvert h(y)\rvert e^{-y} < \lvert h(x)\rvert e^{-y} + \varepsilon.$$

Thus, there is a $z$ such that $\lvert f(y)\rvert \leqslant 2\varepsilon$ for all $y \geqslant z$, and this shows

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} f(t) = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you ! I should have thought to the exponential...

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat trick for this specific question (and the likes of it): Consider the equality $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)  \frac{e^x}{e^x}$$
The differentiability of $f$ allows us to attempt to calculate the limit using l'Hopital's rule. We differentiate the RHS to obtain:
$$\text{RHS} \underbrace{=}_{?} \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(f(x)+f'(x)\right)  \frac{e^x}{e^x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)+f'(x) $$
with the first equality holding *only* if the latter limit exists, and it does.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$f'(t) + f(t) = g(t); \tag 1$

then we have

$\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t) = 0, \tag 2$

and we see that (1) is in fact an ordinary differential equation with, for any $t_0 \in \Bbb R$, $f(t_0)$ the initial condition at $t = t_0$.  It is well-known that the unique solution to (1) is given by

$f(t) = e^{-(t - t_0)}(f(t_0) + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds); \tag 3$

from (3) we have

$\vert f(t) \vert= \vert e^{-(t - t_0)}(f(t_0) + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds) \vert$
$= e^{-(t - t_0)} \vert f(t_0) + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds \vert \le e^{-(t - t_0)}\vert f(t_0) \vert +  e^{-(t - t_0)} \vert \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds \vert; \tag 4$

as for the rightmost integral in (4),

$\displaystyle \vert \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds \vert \le \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)} \vert g(s) \vert ds, \tag 5$

and if $\vert g(t) \vert \le M$ for $t \ge t_0$,

$\displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)} \vert g(s) \vert ds \le M\int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)} = M(e^{(t - t_0)} - 1) \tag 6$

for $t \ge t_0$ as well.  Thus

$ e^{-(t - t_0)} \vert \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t e^{(s - t_0)}g(s) ds \vert \le Me^{-(t - t_0)} (e^{(t - t_0)} - 1) = M(1 - e^{-(t - t_0)}) \le M; \tag 7$

we combine (4) with (7) and obtain

$\vert f(t) \vert \le e^{-(t - t_0)} \vert f(t_0) \vert +  M(1 - e^{-(t - t_0)}) \le   e^{-(t - t_0)} \vert f(t_0) \vert +  M, \tag 8$

again, valid for $t \ge t_0$, provided $\vert g(t) \vert \le M$ for such $t$.

Based upon (2), given $\epsilon > 0$, we may now choose $\tau_0$ sufficiently large that

$\vert g(t) \vert \ \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \; \text{for} \; t \ge \tau_0; \tag 9$

then (8) yields

$\vert f(t) \vert \le  e^{-(t - \tau_0)} \vert f(\tau_0) \vert + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}  \; \text{for} \; t \ge \tau_0;  \tag{10}$

we may now choose $\tau_1 > \tau_0$ sufficiently large that

$ e^{-(t - \tau_0)}\vert f(\tau_0) \vert \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \; \text{for} \; t \ge \tau_1, \tag{11}$

so (10) becomes

$\vert f(t) \vert \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon \; \text{for} \; t \ge \tau_1.  \tag{12}$

We have now shown that, for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\tau_1> 0$ such that, if $t \ge \tau_1$,

$\vert f(t) \vert \le \epsilon, \tag{13}$

which is precisely the assertion that

$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 0. \tag{14}$